# Excel macro scan a cell for multiple values. and loop

Tags: excel, loops, vba

Below I have a program that will go to a sheet (Inventory), look at the employee name, column A, if its the same as above (Last time)

`If Cells(i & ",1").Value = Cells(i - 1 & ",1").Value Then`

then look at a description in column B and if it isn't on the ones that I need, go to the next line and repeat. If it is what I need then copy the row back to sheet J and copy onto there. Rinse Lather Repeat.  However at the moment all it is doing is adding another value to i and moving on, meaning that it is just skipping every second line. What loop do I need to add to make it recheck the next line, ie i=3 for the same thing and possibly discard that as well?

For bonus points, the column A scan is not working. Help on that would be great.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

i = 2
j = 73
k = 3

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Inventory"
Sheets("Inventory").Select
Do Until i = 4495
   If Cells(i & ",1").Value = Cells(i - 1 & ",1").Value Then
       Sheets("Inventory").Select
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       If Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "CONSUMABLES" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "FILTERS - BILLI TRIO" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "FILTERS - ZIP GENERIC" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "GOODS" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "HARDWARE FIXINGS" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "LIGHTING - 50W DICHROIC" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "LIGHTING - COMPACT BC/ES" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "LIGHTING - DICHROIC LAMP" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "LIGHTING - FLURO" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "LIGHTING - PLC LAMP 840/830" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "LIGHTING - PL-L" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "LIGHTING - PULSE STARTER" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "LIGHTING - STANDARD STARTER" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "LIGHTING - T5 FLURO" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "NITROGEN CHARGE" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "OXYGEN / ACETYLENE WELDING" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "R-134A" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "R-22" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "R-407C" _
           Or Cells(i & ",2").Text <> "R-410A" = 0 Then   
               i = i + 1
       Exit If
   Rows(i).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Sheet" & j).Select
   Rows(k).Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   i = i + 1
   k = k + 1
Else
```

Comment: You are incrementing `i` twice per loop.  Once in the if statement and once afterwards.  I'm not sure what you want your code to do, so I can't tell you which to remove/modify.

Comment: I want to Check The value in coloum B with the Big If. If it passes us the coloum (Everything below End if) if it fails repeat on the next line down (i=i+1)

Comment: Can you show the rest of your `Do Until` loop?  Or give a simple example that shows your problem?

Comment: The rest of it is a condition if the coloum A isnt the same as the prvious Cell, making a new sheet and formatting it for use

Comment: Help me understand your logic.  So if Cells(i, 2) contains "CONSUMABLES" you want to copy it or not copy it?

Comment: It also seems like you shouldn't be incrementing i or k anywhere in the code you've provided, but later in the loop.  It's hard to say because you don't show the whole loop.

Comment: there is no `Exit If` function. also you can do this using `Array`. creating sample now...

Comment: Copy it if it does contain one of these values, if it does not ie: "Parking" then move to the next line and reevaluate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()

Dim myarray
Dim wsInv As Worksheet
Dim rngDes As Range, rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim k As Long

Set wsInv = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Inventory")

'~~>Assign all cell in Column A with value
Set rng = wsInv.Range("A2", wsInv.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Address)

'~~> you identified j = 73 so I assign it directly
Set rngDes = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet73").Range("A3")

'~~> assign all the compare values in an array
myarray = Array("CONSUMABLES", "FILTERS - BILLI TRIO", "FILTERS - ZIP GENERIC", _
    "GOODS", "HARDWARE FIXINGS", "LIGHTING - 50W DICHROIC", "LIGHTING - COMPACT BC/ES", _
    "LIGHTING - DICHROIC LAMP", "LIGHTING - FLURO", "LIGHTING - PLC LAMP 840/830", _
    "LIGHTING - PL-L", "LIGHTING - PULSE STARTER", "LIGHTING - STANDARD STARTER", _
    "LIGHTING - T5 FLURO", "NITROGEN CHARGE", "OXYGEN / ACETYLENE WELDING", _
    "R-134A", "R-22", "R-407C", "R-410A")

'~~> Initialize k to 0 to used in offet
k = 0
For Each cel in rng
    If cel.Value = cel.Offset(-1,0).Value Then
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(cel.Offset(0,1).value, myarray, 0)) Then  
            cel.EntireRow.Copy rngDes.Offset(k,0)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

What above does is check every value in Inventory Sheet column A if there are consecutive values.
If there is, i checks it's adjacent cell (Column B) if the value is within the `myarray`.
If yes, then it will copy the entire row to `Sheet73`.
Is this what you need?

Comment: This seems very usable to me, how ever when I run it, it comes to `Set rng = wsInv.Range("A2", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` and comes up with a runtime error saying object required. any chance you can help me here?

Comment: already corrected the code. it should be `Set rng = wsInv.Range("A2", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)`.

Comment: Ive tried your updated one, however it comes up with the same problem. I am not even close to understanding this code, however could it be because ws isnt set as a range at the top?

Comment: oh sorry, my bad :( that should be `Set rng = wsInv.Range("A2", wsInv.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)`. Editing answer now. really sorry mate.

Comment: np, glad it worked. apologies if i supplied untested code :D. sometimes, i have no liberty to test every code.

Comment: Im looking at this code, is there anyway that i can add extra steps in order to make a new sheet if the employees name in coloum A is not the same as the one above, ie i-1?

Comment: yes. you just didn't clear it out in the question. if you want, you post another and completely explain what you really want :D

Comment: Stack overflow isnt quite working for me to do that, but if you could quickly just tell me where i have to put something like an else conditon, that would really help me out

Comment: `Stack overflow isnt quite working for me to do that` what dyou mean? Btw, tell me exactly what you want to do :D You mean if not consecutive, it should be transferred to another sheet? and `to make a new sheet` means that for every non-consecutive name it will create a new sheet? Please elaborate. :D I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Im fairly sure it is my computer more than anything, but it is not allowing me to post another question. If the text in cell k,1 is not the same as the text above, ie new employee, I want to to....... I can fill in the blanks I just need to know where to go and what to put into the code, so I can do. I do plan on making a new sheet and I know what im doing for that its not important.

Comment: Here is the URl for the question, you know what it is, come get some easy points and help us both out @L42 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397867/excel-macro-new-sheeet-if-cell-values-are-different