# excel macro New sheeet if cell values are different

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that will look in column B and determine if the row should be copied to a new cell or if it should move to the next row down, based on the conditions. What I want it to do is to first look in column A, employee names, and if the name in say row k is not the same as in row k-1, then make a new sheet, copy row k to there and then loop around. Eventually, every employee has their own sheet.

```
Sub Sample()

Dim myarray

Dim wsInv As Worksheet
Dim rngDes As Range, rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim k As Long

Set wsInv = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
Set rng = wsInv.Range("A2", wsInv.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Address)
Set rngDes = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A3")

myarray = Array("CONSUMABLES", "FILTERS - BILLI TRIO", "FILTERS - ZIP GENERIC", _
    "GOODS", "HARDWARE FIXINGS", "LIGHTING - 50W DICHROIC", "LIGHTING - COMPACT BC/ES", _
    "LIGHTING - DICHROIC LAMP", "LIGHTING - FLURO", "LIGHTING - PLC LAMP 840/830", _
    "LIGHTING - PL-L", "LIGHTING - PULSE STARTER", "LIGHTING - STANDARD STARTER", _
    "LIGHTING - T5 FLURO", "NITROGEN CHARGE", "OXYGEN / ACETYLENE WELDING", _
    "R-134A", "R-22", "R-407C", "R-410A")

k = 0
For Each cel in rng
    If cel.Value = cel.Offset(-1,0).Value Then
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(cel.Offset(0,1).value, myarray, 0)) Then  
            cel.EntireRow.Copy rngDes.Offset(k,0)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cel`
```

If anyone could at least tell me where I can get to a new sheet based on column A value, that would be amazing, thank you

Comment: hi, saw your comment. btw, if it row k is not the same with row k-1, will it still compare to your array before you copy or create a new sheet immediately and copy?

Comment: if cell(k,1) is NOT the same name as cell(k-1,1) then I want to write in a whole new section of making a new page for it. I can do that part, what I cant do if find where to put a line like that. If cell(k,1) = cell(K-1,1) then go to comparing the array, that works wonders

Comment: I did not follow. I created a code though which will create a new sheet for every employee. If the employee already have a sheet, it will put the data there, if not it will create a worksheet for that employee. Sorry, i'm just guessing what you want. See my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, try this:

```
   Sub Sample()

Dim myarray

Dim wsInv As Worksheet, wsDes As Worksheet
Dim rngDes As Range, rngEmp As Range, cel As Range

Set wsInv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
Set rngEmp = wsInv.Range("A2", wsInv.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)

myarray = Array("CONSUMABLES", "FILTERS - BILLI TRIO", "FILTERS - ZIP GENERIC", _
    "GOODS", "HARDWARE FIXINGS", "LIGHTING - 50W DICHROIC", "LIGHTING - COMPACT BC/ES", _
    "LIGHTING - DICHROIC LAMP", "LIGHTING - FLURO", "LIGHTING - PLC LAMP 840/830", _
    "LIGHTING - PL-L", "LIGHTING - PULSE STARTER", "LIGHTING - STANDARD STARTER", _
    "LIGHTING - T5 FLURO", "NITROGEN CHARGE", "OXYGEN / ACETYLENE WELDING", _
    "R-134A", "R-22", "R-407C", "R-410A")

For Each cel In rngEmp
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, myarray, 0)) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsDes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cel.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If wsDes Is Nothing Then Set wsDes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

        wsDes.Name = cel.Value
        cel(1 - (cel.Row - 1)).EntireRow.Copy wsDes.Range("A1")
        cel.EntireRow.Copy wsDes.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set wsDes = Nothing
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

What above code does is check if value in `Column B` is within the array.
If yes, it will copy data to a `Sheet` named after the employee.
If that employee don't have an existing `Sheet` yet, it will create one.
Not sure if this helps, but give it a try.

Comment: Wow amazing, it is just like skinning a cat in reverse, there is a special job for you when heavens computers break down

Comment: yeah totally amazing. i'm surprised as well. :) One problem though. That code doesn't know how to check duplicates. You should add additional checking with another field reference say Date or whatever to check if that row was already copied before. or better yet, a field with distinct ID. Running the code again and again duplicates the data already copied.

Comment: There are going to be duplicates, an item such as "consumables" can be used 3-4 times per day per job. so im not fussed, moreso just going to hope

Comment: Ive Found a small problem this week at work, it seems to be working fine for the first value, however it is trying to make a new sheet for the second row, which being under the same employee name, itsnt working, rather than adding a new line at teh bottom, thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

So if I read this right, then you want to have column A with employees, column B with something that you want to use to compare, and column C with inventory type. If that's the case, and if this table is sorted on the employees column, then the following modification to what you have should do the trick.

```
k = 0
Dim currentSheet as Worksheet, currentName as String
For Each cel in rng
    'So if column a contains names, 
    'and the name isn't what we have as the current name...
    If currentName <> cel.Value Then
         'reset your counter and your "currentSheet"
         k = 0
         Set currentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
         currentSheet.Name = Left(rng.Value,31)
    End If
    'So as I read your original code, you had your search criteria in column
    'A. I am assuming employee name is now in column A and everything else
    'is shifted over, hence why the additional offset and why the other offset values 
    'have been changed
    If cel.Offset(,1).Value = cel.Offset(-1,1).Value Then
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(cel.Offset(0,2).value, myarray, 0)) Then  
            'This code also copies employee name, I don't know if that is 
            'desired or not. I am thinking if you don't need employee name,
            'the easiest thing to do would be to delete column A in the new sheets
            'in the above if block before you assign a new currentSheet
            cel.EntireRow.Copy currentSheet.Offset(k,1)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cel
```

If you can't sort by employees...then it is a little bit trickier. You'd have to add a function that searches through the sheet names to see if that sheet already exists, then find where you left off on that sheet, and then paste there. Its going to make your life a lot easier if you can sort.

Comment: This code looks good for its place, however whenever i go to use it, it highlights the `.Offset` from the 5th last line and says `method or data member not found` any idea?